# Javascript: how to function if class exists or change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Thank you, everyone!
I am keep going design my game with Javascript.

There is box, id called 'box1'.
Also, there is a hidden button.
I have a function to change the box1 class.

I want to change the visibility if the box1 has the class "glow".
In fact, I am planning to check 9 boxes class. Therefore, I may use && for "if" condition.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (document.$('#box1').classList.contains('.glow')) {
    $(".btn-warning").css('visibility', 'visible');
}});
```

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, you can check for the presence of a class by using `.hasClass()`, e.g. `if ($('#box1').hasClass('.glow')) { ... }`. However, your code is running when the page loads, which is probably not what you want. When do you want to perform this check? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71982094/edit) to include the relevant details.

Comment: Why not add the visibility to your class ```glow``` in your css file?

Answer (score 0):

something like you can design your code

You have a 9 blocks with its like box1, box2, so on

Loops through get all class nodes

```
$("div[id^='box']").foreach(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass(".glow"))
  {
  // your logic
  $(".btn-warning").css('visibility', 'visible');
  }
}
```

I hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your comments.
I change my logic.

I finish the code myself.

`gameboxsize` is the div for `9boxes`.

```
setInterval(function() {
  var gamebox = document.getElementById('gameboxsize');
  var nodesSameClass = gamebox.getElementsByClassName('glow');
  console.log(nodesSameClass.length);
  var winNum = nodesSameClass.length;

  if (winNum === 9) {
    $(".btn-warning").css('visibility', 'visible');
  }
});
```